# Sale with or for VAT refund purposes

Tags: word-choice

Is this expression correct?

To perform sales with VAT refund?

It is a text about Tax Free Shopping. And the sentence is about stores wishing to join Tax Free shopping. In this case, they want to perform sales with VAT refund ?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts. This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions. Without more context there won't be any high quality answers. Please describe a little more, what you are writing about. Furthermore, simple proofreading is off-topic. You should describe clearly what you think is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The EU FAQ calls those shops simply VAT-free.

"The shop will usually display a prominent sign in the window, advertising that it is a ‘tax-free’ or ‘VAT-free’ shop. This may of course be in the local language."

http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/individuals/travelling/travellers-leaving-eu/guide-vat-refund-visitors-eu_en

Answer (score 0):

The verb "perform" usually does not take the direct object "sales". People would certainly understand what you meant, but I think it sounds a bit strange. The verb "conduct" might be better.

Furthermore, "VAT refund" requires a determiner.

A well-formed sentence might be:

> That store will only conduct sales with VAT refunds.

(Because there are multiple sales, I made "VAT refunds" plural, so no determiner is required.)